# JavaScriptCore doesn't work anything else than 'hello, world'

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, javascriptcore

I'm currently writing a Bitcoin-related app in Swift. As there are no native libraries for BIP32/39 available, I decided to go with js ones using JavaScriptCore.

The problem is, almost everything outputs `undefined` in Swift, e.g.:

```
var pip_buffer = new Uint8Array(strength / 8);
```

This one works:

```
var pip_buffer = "Hello, world"
```

Here's my Swift code:

```
var context: JSContext?

private func initJS() {
    context = JSContext()
    if let jsSrcPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "script", ofType: "js") {
        do {
            let jsSrcContents = try String(contentsOfFile: jsSrcPath)
            _ = context?.evaluateScript(jsSrcContents)
        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}

private func getJSVar(name: String) {
    if let vb = context?.objectForKeyedSubscript(name) {
        print("\(vb)")
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    initJS()
    getJSVar(name: "pip_buffer")
}
```

How to make this thing work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [JSValue API Doc](https://developer.apple.com/reference/javascriptcore/jsvalue#1965635) I don't see any reference to `Uint8Array`, which probably means that JavaScriptCore can't convert `Uint8Array` to a "Swift" value.

You can use `Array.from(pip_buffer)` on the JS side to convert your `Uint8Array` to a regular number array, which works.

e.g.

```
    if let vb = context?.evaluateScript("Array.from(pip_buffer)") {
        print("\(vb)")
    }
```

Once converted a regular JS number array, you can also use `JSValue.toArray()` (Swift side), to get it as an array (and can also use `toNumber()`, `toInt32()` or `toUInt32()`, for each item in the array).